# Scroll to a specific tag of another component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to navigate from one component to another on a button click. Like I'm having a nav bar with "Home", "About", ... in the header component

```
<li><a class="text-white" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="text-white" href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a class="text-white" href="#jobs">Opportunities</a></li>
<li><a class="text-white" href="#volunteers">Volunteers</a></li>
<li><a class="text-white" href="#donors">Donors</a></li>
<li><a class="text-white" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

And there is another component called home like this

```
<section id="home">
  <app-home-component></app-home-component>
</section>

<section id="about">
  <app-about></app-about>
</section>

<section id="jobs">
  <app-jobs></app-jobs>
</section>

<section id="volunteers">
  <app-volunteers></app-volunteers>
</section>

<section id="donors">
  <app-donors></app-donors>
</section>
```

Now when I click the about button in the nav bar it should slide to the about component in the home component. I'm not sure how to do it. I tried using id and href but it didn't work. So any suggestions how it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the **header** component add queryParams to the links:

```
<li><a class="text-white" [routerLink]="['/home']" [queryParams]="{id: 'home'}">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="text-white" [routerLink]="['/home']" [queryParams]="{id: 'about'}">About</a></li>
```

in the **home** component check the route for queryParams and if there is any id you should scroll it into the view:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route. queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if (params && params.id) {
            let element = document.getElementById(params.id);
            element && element.scrollIntoView();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the angular feature fragment to let the browser handle it

```
    <a routerLink="" fragment="volunteers"> Volunteers                 </a>
```

Checkout angular fragment